# Installing missing ImageMagick delegate libraries - OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, imagemagick, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, imagemagick-convert

I am working to get ImageMagick installed via homebrew with a few options being passed for the update. But from what I can tell there doesn't seem to be a way to do this on Mountain Lion as it seems to have a pre 'bottled' formula. The two delegates I'd like to install are 'liblqr'  for liquad resizing and 'little-cms' for color profiles. Neither of which seem to be included in the bottled formula.

What I have tried  -
- uninstalling everything (`$ brew uninstall imagemagick liblqr little-cms`)
- reinstalling everything with --force (which seems to be a reco)
- `$ brew edit imagemagick`  (and add the two arguments to the formula)

None of these processes ever show me the delegates added via `$ convert -list configure` and I continue to receive the log errors of...

`` convert: delegate library support not built-in `709396070.jpg' (LQR) @ error/resize.c/LiquidRescaleImage/190 ``

and

convert: delegate library support not built-in `709396070.jpg' (LCMS) @ warning/profile.c/ProfileImage/569.

Is there anything I can do besides building from source? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have a Mountain Lion only problem. On Mavericks I install with:

```
brew install imagemagick --with-liblqr
```